# How do I time an EMMI counter?

Tags: metroid-dread

Avoiding EMMI isn't all too bad once you know the area enough to know your escape routes. But eventually, EMMI will catch up to you.

How do I do an EMMI counter? Or more specifically, when should I counter during the attack animation?

Is it supposed to be the moment the yellow spark flashes? Is there an element of chance? I keep pressing right at that moment but it doesn't always work (even with a good reaction time). I know the game says it's "extremely difficult to gauge" but it can't be *that* difficult to figure out.

Comment: The only time I managed to counter an EMMI was the umpteenth time I was caught while trying to escape from the first one, I threw the (pro) controller on pure frustration, and the button pressed itself when landing. I don't know what the chances were, I might as well been struck by lightning 3 times in a row and that would still be more probable.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with a catch-all answer is that there are multiple EMMI quicktime events, each with different angles (and differently located fatal stab wounds for Samus if you fail!).

I've managed to trigger an EMMI counter a few times now, and I seem to have most luck by ignoring the flash entirely, and instead attempting to proactively react when the EMMI first starts to move (which precedes the Counter flash by fractions of a second).

I have seen no reason to think there's any randomness beyond which cutscene configuration you wind up with, and beyond that I suspect it's something only improved with practice (and the window *is* very tight!).

Comment: I'm thinking it's all in the counter animation that Samus makes ultimately. She'll swing her arm and it takes a brief moment for that animation to play out. So timing wise, it might have to be _just before_ the flash would show.

Comment: @JeffMercado Yep -- I debated whether or not to mention Samus' arm animation in my answer. Essentially you want to have the counter window open _when_ the EMMI starts moving.

Comment: Since there are 2 flashes, I assume we get 2 chances to escape from the EMMI. I've only ever managed to counter them on the first flash so far, though.

Comment: @Nolonar the second I've found to be much harder to time. I've never successfully countered that one. But it should be noted that the second animation Samus makes is a kick. So it stands to reason that you'd want to counter just before the flash occurs so Samus would kick EMMI off as it tries to stab her.